# D3js: Bar to Pie Chart transition - Bar height becomes incorrect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have tried a bar to pie chart transition and I have problem with the height of the bars.They appear to be having  less difference in their height even though the difference between the values(90 and 1) of the bars is large. And the values mapped in the pie chart are perfect.

I solved the problem. It was in the y axis range.

Here is some of the code :

```
  x = d3.scale.ordinal();
  y = d3.scale.linear().range([ h  ,0]); // previously it was [0,h]. This was the problem.

 var g = svg.selectAll(".symbol");
 var t = g.transition()
      .duration(duration / 6);

  t.selectAll("rect")
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.pts0 + d.pts) - 1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return h - y(d.pts) + 1; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.symbol); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Thanks for all the help...

Comment: Could you please post in js fiddle

Comment: Please check the question properly. I've already included the fiddle.

Comment: I think the problem is when computing bar height, you are subtracting a scaled value from absolute (pixels) value.

Comment: i changed my height to .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.pts);}) , similar to the bar graph that I previously did (which works perfectly). But, the problem is still there.

Comment: The rectangles in your code are selected, but never created. The height, position and width of the rectangles don't have any effect in your chart. The rectangles seen in the chart are paths.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was in the y axis range. Instead of [h,0], I've defined it the other way.